# error when publishing an application using Application Loader

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing, loader

ERROR ITMS-9000 "This bundle is invalid. The IPA format requires a top-level directory named Payload, containing only a .app bundle and optional plugins in a Plugins directory." 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your ipa creation process. Check the ipa's content, it's actually a zip file with a special ending that you can unzip. 
Like the error message states, there should be top-level directory /Payload with only one single file app in it: /Payload/YourApp.app.

Comment: I don't understand. In my zip file must be only folder Payload with my .app?

Comment: You should have a file with the extension .ipa (iOS Application, some (Apple) say it stands for 'iOS App Store Package'. This ipa is the App package that you want to upload to Apple. The .ipa Container is a zip archive, so you can rename e.g. MyApp.ipa to MyApp.zip and open it to validate it's structure. There should be a structure like /Payload/MyApp.app inside if it isn't, that's the problem.